# textarea not displaying IE but is getting submitted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, textarea

i have the following function in jQuery and javascript that creates a form element:

```
createEmail: function(title){
        var $emailForm = $('<form>',{action: 'sendEmail.php', id: 'emailForm'});
        var $table = $('<table>');

        $emailForm.append($table);
        var $tr = $('<tr>');
        $tr.append($('<td>',{text: 'Email From:'}));
        $tr.append($('<td>',{html: '<input type="text" value="" name="from"/>'}));
        $table.append($tr);

        $tr = $('<tr>');
        $tr.append($('<td>',{text: 'Email To:'}));
        $tr.append($('<td>',{html: '<input type="text" value="" name="to"/>'}));
        $table.append($tr);

        $tr = $('<tr>');
        $tr.append($('<td>',{text: 'Message Body:'}));
        $tr.append($('<textArea>',{name: 'msg', cols: 50, rows: 10,
                            text: 'Attached is the ' +title+ ' license key file.\nPlease place the file in the same directory as the "check_license.php" file for ' +title+ ' '}));
        $table.append($tr);

        $tr.append('<input type="hidden" value="'+title+'" name="title"/>');

        var $div = $('<div>').append($emailForm).dialog({
                title: 'Email ' + title + ' File',
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    cancel: function(){
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    send: function(){
                        $.post($emailForm.attr('action'), $emailForm.serialize(),function(data){
                            alert(data);
                            $div.dialog('close');
                        })
                    }
                },
                beforeClose: function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        $div.dialog('widget').css('margin','0 auto');

    }
```

For some reason in IE the text area is not showing up and the dialog looks like this when you click on it:[image]

but in chrome and FF it looks normal:
[image]

why is this happening?  the text area still gets submitted to my php as if it has something in it (and when i use dev tools in IE8 it says there is content in it)

So why in IE does it not display an editable textarea?

Thanks....

Comment: Can you try lowercase `textarea`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly, it looks like you're appending your textarea to the row instead of the cell.

Comment: yep that fixed it! thank you so much! nice catch!   why did that only affect IE though?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps IE is not recognizing the `<textArea>`, try `<textarea>`.